# mongoose, nodejs, sort and let specific value to be at the end

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have code like below, it's sorting great but sometimes "N/A" is in values I want to sort. It will show somewhere between "A" and "Z". I would like to have "N/A" values showed as last one`s. Variable 'sort' is from user input.

```
const data = await movie.find().sort(sort)
```

Answer (score 0):

Then just add some extra sort logic:

```
.sort((a, b) => ((b === "N/A") - (a === "N/A")) || sort(a, b))
```

Comment: can you explain details? what is a and b in this function?

Comment: @lukasz the same as in your sort function

Comment: in my case its string like '-Year', 'Rated' etc.